# You or yourself

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, pronouns, sentence-choice

**Which one is correct to use in this context?(all  pronouns refer to the same people)**

---

Your best friend is you.

Your best friend is yourself.

---

Our best friends are ourselves.

Our best friends are we.

Our best friends are us.

---

My best friend is myself.

My best friend is me.

My best friend is I.

---

Her best friend is herself.

Her best friend is her.

Her best friend is she.

---

**And what about these sentences**?

---

My friend is she.

My best friend is her.

---

Her best friend is I.

Her best friend is me.

Comment: The easy solution to all of these is to stop trying to force them into this word order... It's one that I would personally avoid because it sounds odd. The idiomatic phrasing is - "You are your own best friend"... or, the even more idiomatic, famous example is "We are our own worst enemies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 : both can be correct. 
2. option a.
3. option a and b.
4. option a. 
Sentences ---
1. They are both wrong, but for different reasons. option a is not wrong, but the word order is weird : She is my friend is acceptable, but my friend is she is unusual in English. 
2. option 2 is correct.

Is this homework? ;) what you want to study up on is the difference between different types of pronouns (reflexive vs possessive, etc). But always remember, English grammar sometimes follows no rules/logic, only traditions. Hope this helped.